Microsoft Login didn't give any respond(token) to iOS devices
I use react native to create my mobile app and I use Microsoft login. In android device login is success and respond the accessToken but in ios device login is success but does not respond any accessToken or any error message what will be the issue.
I try by giving separate redirect uri for ios but it did't work
I use react-native-app-auth package
This is my Login funtion
    const microsoftSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Login Starts")
      const {accessToken} = await authorize(config);
      console.log(accessToken)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    } 
};

and this is my config file
  issuer: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/*****',
  clientId: '******',
  redirectUrl: 'msauth.org.reactjs.native.example.mobileapp://auth',
  scopes: ['User.Read', 'User.ReadBasic.All'],
  serviceConfiguration: {
    authorizationEndpoint:
      'https://login.microsoftonline.com/******/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
    tokenEndpoint: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/******/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    revocationEndpoint:
      'https://login.microsoftonline.com/******/oauth2/v2.0/logout',
  },
  useNonce: true,
  usePKCE: true,
  additionalParameters: {
    prompt: 'consent',
  },
};

This is a single tenant application
I did all the configuration that are need do before use react-native-app-auth package but it didn't works in iOS devices.
I need to fix this issue or I done something wrong in the code
